# How do you delete Twilio logs?

Tags: twilio

I can't seem to be able to delete the error logs in Twilio. Need help

did not see an option to delete. Only a filter button. I am not a programmer. I just need the basic procedure. I am sorry I can't think of anymore questions to get to 180 characters. Maybe if I just keep asking it will let me finish,

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to delete logs is programmatically. For this, you need the [account credentials](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136147-Where-are-my-Twilio-Test-Credentials-) from the Twilio console and a short code snippet.
This is the Node.js code that removes all message and call logs:

```js
/************************************* 
Run this code to remove all user data from the message and call logs
*************************************/

require("dotenv").config();
const client = require("twilio")();

console.log(`Clearing logs for account ${process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID}.`);

(async () => {
  let messages = await client.messages.list({});

  await Promise.all(
    messages.map((message) => {
      console.log(message.body);
      return client.messages(message.sid).remove();
    })
  );
  console.log(`Deleted ${messages.length} messages successfully.`);

  const calls = await client.calls.list({});

  await Promise.all(
    calls.map((call) => {
      return client.calls(call.sid).remove();
    })
  );
  console.log(`Deleted ${calls.length} calls successfully.`);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way to remove all things in Twilio I implemented in the job project:

It has its advantages than in example above, that Promise.allSettled executes everything, even there was one error in middle of message deletion. Promise.all is stopped, if something happens in way of executing.

And, if failedPromises is more than 0, you could call the deleteSMSLogs function recursively and again until it has no errors

---

In code we use custom errors with integrated Sentry and log library (logger). Replace `MessageDeletionFailedError, Twilio and logger.info` with your log and error reporting tools

```js
const twilioClient = twilio(accountSid, authToken)

export async function getMessages(opts: MessageListInstanceOptions) {
  return await twilioClient.messages.list(opts)
}

const deleteSMSLogs = async ({ phoneNumber }): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    const smsMessagesByTo = await getMessages({ to: phoneNumber })
    const smsMessagesByFrom = await getMessages({ from: phoneNumber })
    const smsMessages = [...smsMessagesByTo, ...smsMessagesByFrom]

    if (smsMessages.length > 0) {
      const log = `[DataDeletion] ${smsMessages.length} sms messages were found by ${phoneNumber}.`
      logger.info(log)

      const result = await Promise.allSettled(
        smsMessages.map(async (smsMessage) => {
          try {
            await smsMessage.remove()
          } catch (err) {
            throw new MessageDeletionFailedError({
              message: `[DataDeletion] Deletion SMS message ${smsMessage.sid} failed. Reason: ${err.message}`,
              context: {
                phoneNumber,
                smsSid: smsMessage.sid,
              },
            })
          }
        }),
      )

      const failedPromises = result.filter((p) => p.status === 'rejected') as PromiseRejectedResult[]

      if (failedPromises.length > 0) {
        throw new MessageDeletionFailedError({
          message: '[DataDeletion] One or more message deletions failed',
          context: { failedPromises },
        })
      }
    } else {
      logger.info(`[DataDeletion] Current user with ${phoneNumber} doesn't have sms logs in twilio`)
    }
  } catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof MessageDeletionFailedError) throw err

    throw new TwilioError(err)
  }
}
```